# Definition of differential forms of class $C^{k}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, tangent-spaces

Take a real differentiable manifold of class $C^k$ and $\omega$ a differential form of degree $q$ on $M$. The definition that I'm using is the following:

> $\omega$ is a function on $M$ such that for each $x \in M$, $\omega(x)$ is a multilinear alternating function on $(T_xM)^q$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now the professor talk about $C^k$ forms but no definition is given explicitly. I have the following guess. I know that given a point $x$ "locally" (in local charts) in a neighborhood of $x$ the form is given by $\omega = \sum\limits_{I} u_I dx_I$ where $I$ is a multi-index and $u_I: M \to \mathbb{R}$. Now I think that $\omega$ is $C^k$ if for each $x$ every $u_I$ is of class $C^k$.

I didn't find a text where this definition is given explicitly. Can anyone help me to understand it?

Comment: Your definition is correct. The regularity of the form $\omega$ is the regularity of the component functions $u_I$.

Comment: Have you checked Lee's smooth manifolds, or Do Carmo's book?

Comment: If the manifold is of class $C^k$, then differential forms/vector fields can only be or class $C^{k-1}$.

Comment: I don't understand, why?

Comment: @LuckyS If a manifold $M$ is of $C^k$ regularity, then its tangent and cotangent bundles $TM$ and $T^*M$, which are defined thanks to the derivatives of the transitions functions of $M$, are of class $C^{k-1}$.